# Does this converge to ln(x)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I haven't went through a proper course in analysis nor calculus, so I'm not totally sure about what I'm doing. I read Euler's Elements of Algebra, and since I've been playing around with series.

Using the method laid down in said text I 'expanded' $\frac{1}{x}$ into an infinte series. First I made it digestible $\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{x+1}{x+1}=\frac{x+1}{x^2+x}$ and then divided it, which resulted in: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  (x-1)^n=\frac{1}{x}$$ I read in a compilation of series and products that series are used to find integrals, so I integrated it and got: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} (x-1)^n}{n} = \ln(x)$$
I graphed partial sums of both and they look good. If I'm not wrong, they are exact at the point at infinity, which depends to an extent in a result of Euler's: that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n = \frac{1}{2}$. Although the partial sums never seem to get far out of the interval $[0, 2]$, which is to be expected for $x=2$ in the first series, they still confuse me with regards to the rest of the function. Are they actually equal to
the whole the function, or do they only converge for an interval?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series

Comment: @Gary Thank you! I expected it to not be new, but now I know where to search.